# Prevent jQuery UI menu focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selection

How do I prevent a jQuery UI menu from focusing on the menu when an item is clicked.

I have a select menu which when an item is clicked it applies an action straight away, then the menu closes.

Because jQuery UI is triggering the focus event on click (line 10956 of http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js), it loses the selection in Chrome (Firefox seems to work).

```
...
} else if ( !this.element.is( ":focus" ) ) {
    // Redirect focus to the menu
    this.element.trigger( "focus", [ true ] ); // <----- this line
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: your html and code would still help, the code for your menu and whatever else is your code

Comment: I did not try, but what about $( ".selector" ).menu({
    focus: function() { return false; }
});

Comment: Anyway you can make a jsFiddle for the question, would help a ton. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to extend the jquery.ui.menu prototype with custom values for specific methods/properties you need to implement.  You can make a new widget that uses $.extend to do this in jquery.  Here's a nice example of extending the menu widget to have it use form inputs (authored by Kris Borchers):

1. the demo page is here:
   http://kborchers.github.com/jquery-ui-extensions/menu/inputmenu.html
2. the scripts are defined like this;

   //this is the core jquery ui library
   < script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js" >< /script >
   //this is the custom input menu widget that extends the default menu widget
   < script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.menu.inputmenu.js" >

3.
evaluate this pattern for extending the default menu widget:

```
    /*
 * jQuery UI Input Menu Extension
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Kris Borchers
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 *
 * http://github.com/kborchers/jquery-ui-extensions
 */
(function( $ ) {

**var proto = $.ui.menu.prototype,
    originalRefresh = proto.refresh;

$.extend( proto, {**
    refresh: function() {
        originalRefresh.call( this );
        var that = this;
......
...
..
.
```

see github source here:
https://github.com/kborchers/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/menu/jquery.ui.menu.inputmenu.js

If you follow this pattern, you can customize any widget to meet your needs.

Hope this helps.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

My quick fix solution is to `setTimeout` 0 and do the focus.
Turns out the setTimeout triggers the menu to do it's focus back to itself,
so if you focus before the setTimout, it will focus back to the menu;

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#input-id').focus();
},0);
```

Another quick fix is to do a click programmatically anywhere,
this cancels the menu's focus back to itself.

```
    $(document).click();
or
    $('#input-id').click();
```